# How do I check whether data is waiting before trying to read (VBA, serial port)?

Tags: vba, ms-access, serial-port

I have an Access database that I'm using to log when items are received. When received, they're scanned in by a unique barcode and I want to log that. The computers running this Access front end are also used for other things, which necessitated the need to use the serial emulation on my scanners (direct/keyboard emulation input isn't an option).

Using Open, I can read from the serial port and all is well unless there is no data waiting to be read--in which case, the Access front end becomes unresponsive for a few seconds. As these computers are used for other tasks, I can't afford to have unresponsiveness.

I've tried using EOF and LOF and both return an error (bad file number) or simply don't function as expected.

How do I check whether information is available to read before attempting Input()?

Edit: let me be more specific. EOF seems to only work for the first read but then always returns true so it skips every attempt to read afterward. LOF always returns bad file name of number.

```
fNum = FreeFile
Open "COM5" For Input As fNum
...
Do While Not EOF(fNum)
 tmp = Input(1, fNum)
  If tmp = vbCr or tmp = vbCrLf then
   ...
  Else
   myStr = myStr & tmp
  End If
Loop
```

Comment: are you having on error resume next somewhere ? remove that and catch errors with labels and if you need to loop, keep the doEvents on

Comment: Error handling won't solve the issue I'm having, unfortunately. However, I think I've come up with a workaround since Access (at least 2013) stalls only the instance with this code so I can run two front end databases with one taking care of this loop and the other taking care of everything else.